# Can I create an "unlimited" values variable?

Tags: 7, configuration

I'm trying to create an exclude list of sorts that is configurable via the variable admin interface. I have created lots of single value variables, but never a variable as an array where through the interface the user can "Add" another field/value like you can on nodes with "unlimited" field values.

Can this be done with the Variable module?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well it will scale, but here is an example for a `multiple` variable in the Variable issue queue https://drupal.org/node/2019629

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_info().
 */
function MY_MODULE_variable_info($options) {
    // Use '[custom]' as a placeholder for the variable name.
    // It will set these properties ('type' and 'multiple') automatically.
    $variables['custom_vars_[custom]'] = array(
        'title'        =>    t('Custom multiple variable'),
        'group'        =>    'site_information',
        'repeat'    =>    array('type' => 'string', 'default' => 'some default value'),
    );
    // if you need to expose your custom variable as token
    // you have to set 'token' key as TRUE,
    // and ought to set the properties (name, description and type)
    // Notice that 'first' it is a name of variable defined in custom_variable_options().
    $variables['custom_vars_first'] = array(
                    'token' => TRUE,
                    'title' => 'Custom variable',                        // name
                    'description' => 'My first variable description',    // description
                    'type'    => 'string'                                    // type
                    );
  return $variables;
}
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_type_info().
 * @return
 *  An array of information defining variable types.
 *  The array contains a sub-array for each variable type
 *  with the variable type as the key.
 *  The possible attributes are the same as for hook_variable_info().
 */
function MY_MODULE_variable_type_info() {
    $type['custom'] = array(
        'title' => t('Custom variables'),
        'type'    => 'select',
        'options callback' => 'custom_variable_options',
    );
    return $type;
}
/**
 * Callback for custom options.
 * @return
 *  An array of variables with the variable name as the key.
 */
function custom_variable_options($variable, $options) {
  return array(
    'first'  => t('My first variable', array(), $options),
    'second' => t('My second variable', array(), $options),
    'third'  => t('My third variable', array(), $options),
  );
}
```

I dont think this is exactly what you want -- but may give you some ideas (it does the `multiple` value per "variable". I'm not sure offhand how you build a variable_form to edit the values in `function custom_variable_options()`.